# How do I make it not show dots less than x chars?

Tags: php

if less than x don't show a "..."

```
<?php echo substr(stripslashes($row['news_title']), 0, 20). ".."; ?>
```

I have it to show more than x if more than 20, but it shows "..." when there's 10 chars. Is there anyway I could have it not to show?

any tutorials?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try like

```
<?php echo substr(stripslashes($row['news_title']), 0, 20);
      if(strlen($row['news_title']) > 20)
          echo ".."; 
?>
```

Comment: should also `stripslashes` before looking at length

Comment: @CrayonViolent Should not `stripslashes` in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [CSS tricks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow#Values), but this would be the code for doing it server-side:

```
if (strlen($row['news_title']) <= 20) {
    echo htmlspecialchars($row['news_title']);
} else {
    echo htmlspecialchars(substr($row['news_title'], 0, 20)), '...';
}
```

Note that `strlen()` counts bytes and not characters per se; this is important when you start working with Unicode, in which case you may want to consider using [`mb_strlen()`](http://php.net/mb_strlen).

Btw, using `stripslashes()` is somewhat of a red flag; if your quotes come out as escaped, the problem lies somewhere else and shouldn't be a problem of the presentation layer ... in fact, you *should* be using [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) instead.

Answer (score 0):

This would do.

```
<?php echo strlen(stripslashes($row['news_title']))>20 ?substr(stripslashes($row['news_title']), 0, 20)."...":stripslashes($row['news_title']); ?>
```

Comment: This will show only "..." for content longer than 20 and the first 20 characters otherwise... not quite what the question called for.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write your own sub string function:
it can be somthing similar like this
http://www.sranko.com/nwP3LFit